# How to approximate bounded exponential integral?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

Does the integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x(t_a)} \frac{(1-e^{-x})}{x} dx$ where $0<x(t_a)$ have an analytical form?
Does an approximation exist for this integral?
Is it possible to approximate this integral using the [Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand the integrand as a series and integrate term by term getting
$$x - x^2/4 + x^3/18 - x^4/96 + x^5/600 + O(x^6)$$
It will converge everywhere, and quickly for small $x$

Comment: Thank you. What's $O(x^6)$?

Comment: Any reference on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The general term is $\frac {-(-x)^n}{n\cdot n!}.\quad $  $O(x^6)$ means terms with powers of $x$ at least $6$.